# How can I track resource usage on Ubuntu over time?

Tags: performance, ram, swap

I am thinking of wanting to get an idea about how my system is running over a 24 hour period or maybe 48 hours.  It would be desirable to see if there is any period where the cpu and memory resources were being used at close to 100%.  Disk thrashing would be another area of concern too.  That would show when I don't have enough memory and so it becomes necessary to heavily use the disk swap file area.  I don't know if it is possible to see heavy use of RAM, as opposed to processor cache vs. the situation where there just isn't enough memory.  As an example, I can see times when disk usage is at 100%.  Now, that does not mean that my disk is full.  I think, I was actually seeing that on a system where I was running Windows.  It was showing disk usage at 100%, and it did not mean that the disk was full.

Does anyone know of a product or application that would show this kind of information?  I know about top and htop.  They don't seem to show any kind of output over an extended period of time.  I guess I am talking about those times, when for example, features available on AWS would cause an extra server or two to spin up temporarily.

I have a system where that is not an option.
Thanks in advance for any tips.
Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sysstat` and `sar` commands for extract and analyse stats on your computer over the time.

Here a good tutorial to do what you want:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment on the other answer so I'm re-answering; but the package is actually sysstat, with three total "s" characters. You can install with:

sudo apt-get install sysstat

And I personally prefer this tutorial:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/monitor-linux-performance-with-sysstat/